# Cron job fails when the php file calls a function from another php. file

Tags: php, cron

I have a `cron` job set up to run testemail.php. This works fine, every minute. (Ubuntu localhost, php5)

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php5 -q /var/www/cocoraco/portfolio/html/testemail.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I have a second file `findandemail.php` which runs some Database tasks and sends email. The email function is defined in (and I did include it as follows) `"../scripts/functions.php"`.  It does not work, while the testemail.php still works.

`Cron` in this case looks like

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php5 -q /var/www/cocoraco/portfolio/html/testemail.php > /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * /usr/bin/php5 -q /var/www/cocoraco/portfolio/find/findandemail.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

As a test, If i copy code from testemail.php to findandemail.php, that section runs fine sending a dummy email. I am new to `cron`.

Can anyone shed some light? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the file `/var/www/cocoraco/portfolio/scripts/functions.php` _does_ exist right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing code like this your code runs at `/usr/bin` so if you `include ../scripts/functions.php` your code looks for the file at `/usr/scripts/functions.php`

I like to use the `__FILE__` magic constant to include files very bulletproof:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../scripts/functions.php');
```

This should do the trick for you.

Comment: Hmmm that probably looks like it. I will check it out and post back. But one question remains. The Cron finds the `findandemail.php` and the '../scripts/functions.php' is called from there. So should nt the directory automatically change?

Comment: No the script is executed from the cron user's home directory or from the binary directory if no home exists. You could specify the directory in the cronjob however: `* * * * * cd /var/www/cocoraco/portfolio/find/; /usr/bin/php5 -q /var/www/cocoraco/portfolio/find/findandemail.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: That worked. Thank you. One last clarification. If I echo `dirname(__FILE__).'/../scripts/functions.php'`, it gives `/var/www/cocoraco/portfolio/html/../scripts/checkuserlog.php`. It works, but I should not use the `../` infront of the `scripts/filename.php`, Correct?

Comment: No thats perfectly correct that way. Btw, you can use http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-include-path.php to include the ../scripts directory in your path and then do an `include filename.php` only. This is especially useful if you need to include many different files from that directory.

Answer (score 0):

I never use php as the executable for the cron task,

I'd recommend using wget and logging the output to a file (depending on your script)

Something like:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * *  *   *    wget -bqc http://domain/testemail.php
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, Can you tell me why you never use php as executable? I will check out the suggestions from the responses and post back.

Comment: executing files directly with php doesn't seem to execute them the same way as you would serving them with apache, configurations differ often, to prevent configurations issues I just go with a wget.

Comment: Ok. I guess I will end up meeting those issues down the lane. :) Thanks!